# easeljs animate endAngle of arc

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

using easeljs how do I animate the endAngle of arc

I tried to make my own property by `pie.setMyAngle = 0.1;`   and then increment it in the tick but that did not work

```
function init() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('easel');
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    var pie = new createjs.Shape();
    pie.setMyAngle = 0.1;
    pie.graphics.beginFill("rgba(255,255,255,1)").arc(75, 75, 75, 0, Math.PI * pie.setMyAngle, false).lineTo(75, 75).closePath();

    stage.addChild(pie);

    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);

    function handleTick() {
        pie.setMyAngle += 0.1; //not working
        pie.x += 1
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing custom properties (e.g. `setMyAngle`) doesn't automatically update your shape; you'll have to redraw yourself. For example, you could move your drawing code into the `handleTick` method:

```
function handleTick() {
    pie.setMyAngle += 0.1;
    pie.x += 1;
    pie.graphics.clear();
    pie.graphics.beginFill("rgba(255,255,255,1)").arc(75, 75, 75, 0, Math.PI * pie.setMyAngle, false).lineTo(75, 75).closePath();
    stage.update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too. I needed to know how to **draw a circular sector in Easeljs**. For reference: [method arc](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_arc)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fun little bit of animation [TweenJS + DrawingAPI](https://github.com/sebastianderossi/amusement/tree/master/DrawingAPI/Arc_Drawing) have a look :D, might help someone out.